# Xcode Erorr: Valid Provisioning Profile Not Found

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ios4

I'm getting all sorts of errors and problems with XCode 4.1 GM for Lion (I have Lion GM).

When I try to run my app on my iPhone, I get this error.  How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Just Check this solved solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to window -> organizer -> click the devices tab, and then select Provisioning profiles. This should list the provisioning profiles you have imported into xcode. Click each one, if they are not valid there will be a stripped yellow/brown bar on the top of the screen and a warning. If you have invalid profiles ensure that they have not expired, and that you have the valid developer profiles to go along with them.

On at least one occasion I found that removing all my profiles, from xcode as well as from my device, and re-importing them solved my problem.

Comment: Hmm, well it works on my phone under the devloper profile but when i change code signing to distibution, it doesn't work.  I think it just a bug with xcode, I was able to submit the update fine.