# XCode - Can I debug an iOS app on an iphone that is not my own?

Tags: xcode, debugging, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am testing an app, and have figured out how to distribute it (I use test flight and it works great).

But I am running into trouble on one of the test devices (my wife's.  uses a different apple id).  I want to be able to run the app on her phone in debug mode, attached to XCode - NOT as a distribution.

Her UDID is already attached to my provisioning profile.  I added her device (to the portal) and then edited both the iosteam distribution profile, and the development profile and downloaded them and installed them on xcode.   - distribution is working fine-.  Debug fine on my phone.

But when I try to run in debug mode on her phone, I get "A valid provisioning profile for this  executable was not found."

I have read through all the threads on that message, and none apply.  I have set my Target code signing options correctly, and all profiles are appearing as valid.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have gotten it working - thus answering my own question.

The first answer on this thread advised that I simply recreate my provisioning profile, but instead of downloading it, simply refresh my xcode view.  Which I did. And now it is working.

[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found... (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again)

Comment: Well done answering your own question. You should mak it as answered so it will be removed from the list of un answered questions.