# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found when trying to run my app on device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am banging my head against this for over  a day now, I had uploaded an app to the apple store some days ago, it was rejected. I made the changes and now want to test the app on my phone again, each time I do I get a weird message telling me that there is no valid provisioning profile. I am a newbie to iOS.

I checked various questions googled around and everything is set up as explained. Why this weird error.

Clicking on window> organiser I see both my valid profile and my iPhone with a green signal. I wonder where the problem is! Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For testing App in to your device you need to do following steps:

- From the [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) you need to add your device UDID from
  [image]

[image]

[image]

- After adding Device UDID you need to create Creating a Developer provisional profile and select all device.
- Download this created Developer provisional profile and install as we did normally
- In Xcode setting correct Bundel Identifire that is you setting in to developer provisional profile `(com.xyz.devTesting)`
- setting code sign from `target-->build phase-->code` sign choose developer provisional that must appear in to list.

now all set and connect you device with xcode and run you project that must run in to you device.

Answer (score 5):

+1 to banging my head against the wall for a day or two...

Also check this setting:

> Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Provisioning Profile

What worked for me was setting it to "Automatic" after following the steps here:
[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found... (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again/26383395#26383395)

Comment: Dudebro, iOS is crazy - I stick to the shallows - Android! :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your build settings. There's an option `Code Signing Identity`. You should fill it with iPhone Developer certificate and **Development** provision profile

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly started getting this msg when trying to run my app on the iPhone (using XCode 7.2). There had been no issue previously. After several unsuccessful hours of trying various solutions on the forums, I started doing diffs against my source control repository.

In my case, it turned out that some how the product bundle identifier had been replaced by ${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER} in the project's .plist file. I changed this back to the actual bundle identifier string, and the problem went away.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find the issue until I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this problem after changing the Team and Bundle ID of my app. After reading all the similar issues on SO for this and finding no solution that worked for me, I finally stumbled on what was wrong:

**The App Target Signing was set up correctly, but the Tests Target wasn't.**

After changing the Team and Bundle ID I hadn't tried running the tests. Once I corrected that (Xcode showed an error in the Target > General > Signing screen) both the app and Test Targets ran on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this cycle before, with resetting/reissuing certificates and profiles. Note that some info is cached.

If you get the endless loop about valid provisioning profiles, **make sure you do a CLEAN build** after changes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013778-CH1-INSTALLPROFILE