# Xcode 7.0.1 app installation failed only on iOS 9.0.2 device

Tags: ios, xcode

I was able to install IPA on an iOS9.0.1 device but not on an iOS9.0.2 device. I am getting an app installation error.

[[image: xcode 7.0.1 app installation error][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsUfa.png)

I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and am creating my IPA using the steps below:

1. Product -> Archive -> Export
2. Save for Ad Hoc Deployment -> Next
3. Select Apple certificate for adhoc deployment
4. Export one app for all compatible devices
5. IPA created successfully
6. Xcode -> Window -> Devices
7. Select iPad device
8. Click on + icon to install new app
9. Select IPA and install.
10. "App Installed Error A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

I think its not a provisioning file error because I am able to install the same build on an iOS9.0.1 device using same distribution profile.

Comment: Ad Hoc profiles contain a list of devices they can be installed on.  Is your 9.0.2 device included?

Comment: Thanks Philip. That was missing. Also I have created IPA for enterprise Deployment and it worked now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found... (again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again)