# Getting a code sign error.It says "Provisioning profile could not be found" in my local machine

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting sick of this. My RCSClient project was working fine till yesterday. I got the update from my smartSVN and now I am getting this error telling that the provisioning profile could not be found. What am I missing? The attachments are here.
[image: snapshot of the error]

So I did the following steps.
1. I went to the devices of the Xcode, clicked on the iPad and show provisioning profile, only to find the ad-hoc profile was installed.
[image]
2. After finding the provisioning profile , I am setting the provisioning profile in my settings.
[image: snapshot showing provisioning profile installed.]

3. Setting the provisioning profile and running the code .[image: Final code-sign error.]

Comment: what are your build settings for provisioning profile?
please provide some screenshots and check if your provisioning profile is still valid on the apple member center

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349300/3051458](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349300/3051458)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error message again. The bundle identifier for your project (found in the Info.plist or the target's settings) is set to `com.RCSClient`. Whereas the mobileprovision is created with a bundle id `com.comverse.RCSClient`. You need to make sure the bundle id used for your mobileprovision and the bundle id specified in your project settings are the same.