# Xcode 7.2 App installation failed, A valid provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

Everything was working great until It suddenly stopped to work. I tried somemany things that I dont know if I broken it

If I try to debug on the iPhone with a valid Provisioning Profile with explicit Bundle Identifier( I also tested wilcard, and same message) it say

> "App Installation failed, A valid provisioning profile for this
>   executable was not found"

If I change the Bundle identifier to the first was that I was using ( I revoke all the certificates) it say

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.bundleidentifier.darwins' is not
>   available. Please enter different string

I dont know what more I can do!

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again

Comment: can you check the case sensitivity of the bundle id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the date of the iPhone.

I added 6 months a few days ago, and today plus 6 month it exceed the profile expiry date.

-Make sure your device date doesn't exceed profile expiry date.
-Make sure your profile has not expired